# CSS display property cannot be set when working with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a view where I need to set visibility for a `div` element from a controller, so when one logic is executed it sets `visibility: hidden` or `display: none` and when another logic is executed it sets `visibility: visible` or `display:block`.

When `View` is rendered, I'm looking at the source and see the correct styles for div,however, when `visibility:hidden`, it still displays the content inside of a `div` tag.

This is the fragment from my `VIEW`:

```
<div id="review" style="display:'<%:Model.Visibility%>'">
   <p>
       REVIEW:
              <%:ViewData["Review"]%>
    </p>        
        <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="OK"/>
</div>
```

This is the fragment from controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(EsafeModel model,string submit, string create)
{
        var button = submit ?? create;
        model.Visibility = "none";
        ViewData["done"] = null;

        EsafeActions eSafe = new EsafeActions(model.Corporation, model.Region, model.PortfolioName);

        if (button.Equals("Create"))//user clicks create. We need to validate the fields and display the review section
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)//pass validation for the entire form
            {
                if (ESafeData.ValidateData(eSafe))//if validated
                {
                    ViewData["Review"] = ESafeData.CreateReview(eSafe);
                    model.Visibility = "block";
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("message", "The region should be 2 characters long.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("message", "Creation of Data failed. Please correct errors and try again.");
            }
        }
        else if (button.Equals("OK"))//need to insert data
        {
            if (ESafeData.Create(eSafe))
            {
                ModelState.Clear();
                if (ESafeData.Create(eSafe))
                {
                    ViewData["Message"] = "E-Safe data created!!!";
                    model.Visibility = "none";
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewData["Message"] = "Failed to Create E-Safe Data";
                }
            }
        }
        return View(model);
  }
```

This is the model:

```
public class EsafeModel
{
    string visibility = "hidden";

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Required Field")]
    [DisplayName("Corporation")]
    public string Corporation { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
    [DisplayName("Region")]
    public string Region { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
    [DisplayName("Portfolio Name")]
    public string PortfolioName { get; set; }

    public string Visibility
    {
        get { return this.visibility; }
        set { this.visibility = value; }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.

My `div` definition was wrong: `<div id="review" style="display:'<%:Model.Visibility%>'">`

Do not need single quotes